# Краткость и простота

Tags: словообразование

Как назвать одним словом состояние человека который распределил и спланировал всё свои правильные действия и поступки и больше ни за что не переживает?

Comment: Смотря почему кто-то переживал до этого.

Answer (score 1):

Например "умиротворенность / умиротворение".
Умиротворение — это состояние спокойствия, безмятежности в мыслях и в чувствах, когда всё ясно и понятно и нет нужды в опасениях.
ru.wikipedia.org

Comment: Я бы рассмотрел другое слово, если следовать вашей мысли - "смирение". Потому что эти слова отличаются, как мир и мiр. Умиротворять - мирить врагов, но смiрять - владеть собой, не давать воли страстям.

Comment: Уважаемый Буратино, если довериться гугл-справке, то дореформенное написание слова «смирение» (и его производных) будет выглядеть так (а не иначе): смиреніе, Смирновъ, смирно, смирный.

Comment: https://sdamp.ru/news/n6728/  
Понятие «смиреніе» соотносится с добродетелью, предполагающей умеренность в каких бы то ни было желаниях / претензиях. Происхождение слова связывают с корнем мер, поскольку в самых древних текстах оно писались с буквой «ѣ»: съмѣренъ, съмѣрити (умерить, смягчить, подавить). Но под влиянием созвучия со  словами примириться, примирение и общей установке на «примирение с действительностью» они стали ассоциироваться с принятием окружающего мира таким, каков он есть, и писаться с буквой «и».

Comment: Обсуждемый вопрос формулирует деятельную позицию  в отношениях с окружающим миром (планировать свои действия и поступки).  О пассивном «принятии окружающего мира таким, каков он есть» или о «смирении» речи (в вопросе) не идет.

Comment: Хорошо, смирение от слова мера - "Таким образом мы можем говорить о смирении, и как о знании своей меры." с азбуки. Почему если смирение, то это пассивное принятие? вы сильно заблуждаетесь, это как раз очень активная позиция смирения своих страстей и энергии направление в созидательное русло. Это очень обывательское отношение к смирению.Можно без "уважаемый"), уважаемый гуарантин.